# I simply want verification that $\sum_{2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x-1} = \sum_{1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sorry to bother.  Up late studying and want to know for sure that $\sum_{2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x-1} = \sum_{1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x}$?

It sure seems that way since:

$$\sum_{2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x-1} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2-1} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3-1} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{4-1} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{5-1} + \cdots = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{4} + \cdots$$

Which would be equal to
$\sum_{1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x}$

Thanks!

Idle

Comment: This is nothing to do with the specific sum you are just shifting the index? Like it you start from (1/2)^1 then it doesn't matter how you write "1": You can write it as $n$ for $n=1$ or $n-1$ for $n=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current version of the question it is correct because it is just an index shift.  Both sides of the equality converge absolutely and you can identify the terms on one side with the terms on the other.  It is just a shift of the index by $1$.  The sum is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

We can just look at how exponents change. For left side, the exponent is from 2-1 = 1 to infinity, and if we look at the right side, we are also looking from 1 to infinity. Thus, what we have are same. If you are confused about this infinity, you might want to look at Hilbert's Hotel.